# Community Site vs Project Site

Tags: community

What is the key difference between a community site and project site? What determines if I should prefer one to the other. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Project Site – this site template is used for managing and collaborating on a project. Project site coordinates project status and all additional information relevant to the project.

Community Site – a site where the community members can explore, discover content and discuss common topics.

So depending upon your requirements you can select any one. Project site is mainly used for project related tasks whi;e community site used for collabration.

http://blog.cloudshare.com/2012/12/06/sharepoint-2013-site-templates/